# Hashability and immutability doubts in Python

Tags: python, list, set, immutability

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't answer it by myself.
I'm trying to learn Python and while I was exploring the idea that `sets` can't contain mutable objects. I tried different scenarios using a `list` inside a `set` and arrived to a point where I was putting a `list` inside a `tuple` inside a `set`, getting the following:

```
a = ([1,2,3],)
type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
S = {1,2,3,a}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    S = {1,2,3,a}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

```
c = ((1,2,3),)
type(c)
<class 'tuple'>
S = {1,2,3,c}
>>> S
{1, 2, 3, ((1, 2, 3),)}
```

So `a` and `c` are both `tuples` but one has an **unhashable** type inside (a `list`). So, I would assume that a better statement for `sets` would be that they can't contain **unhashable** objects. Anyway, my doubt is, how does this process occur for python in terms of knowing which `tuple` in this case is valid to be used in a `set`?

Thank you all,
SP

Comment: Unhashable and immutable are strongly correlated. You can’t (shouldn’t) hash a mutable object, so mutable objects are unhashable…

Answer (score 0):

sets require their elements to be hashable. So, mutable types are not hashable because a change of their values would change the hash and which in turn breaks the whole property of hash.

**Note:**
if you explicitly define `__hash__()` then you could do for immutable types also.

Comment: Theoretically a class that provides its own `__hash__` method could allow mutations that don't affect the hash.